# hashtable values reordered

Tags: java

I have a hashtable, which contains strings for example, when I use put method as below

```
 hashtable.put("1","A");
 hashtable.put("1","B");
 hashtable.put("1","C");
 hashtable.put("1","D");
 hashtable.put("1","E");
```

Then when I try to print it back it doesn't print in same order, Any one knows why would something like this happen?

```
 Collection c = ht.values();
 Iterator itr = c.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext())
 System.out.println(itr.next());
```

Thanks 
Max

Comment: I don't think you meant to use the same key for all entries ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you want to print items in order.

Answer (score 4):

A [`Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) **does not** guarantee any kind of ordering.

If you want to preserve insertion order, use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). However, the contract is slightly different than a `Hashtable` in that it allows null elements.

Answer (score 2):

That is simply the property of a hash table -- it makes no guarantee about ordering. Do you want to use a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead?

Answer (score 1):

HashTable doesnot keep order.It will print randomly.You should go for LinkedHashMap.You can use LinkedHashMap in the same manner as you did for HashMap.Just put LinkedHashMap in place of HashMap.LinkedHashMap keeps the order of data in which you enter into it.

Comment: (Strictly speaking, the ordering of the elements of a HashTable or HashMap is not random.  For a given set of set of keys (and hash codes) and a given insertion order, you will get the same ordering of entries.  But that ordering will *typically* be hard to predict and may appear to be random.)